# get browser session in mysql

Tags: mysql, browser, session-cookies

How can i get browser session in mysql. Any idea thanks in advance.

Comment: `MySQL` does not interact with the `HTTP` server directly. You should pass it from the server library, like `PHP`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the session information via MySQL as it is only a database and not handling any HTTP stuff.

Fetch the information you need via PHP and then store it from there in MySQL.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Answer (score 0):

The location of your browser session depends on the framework you use and also on the fact whether you use the db to store your session. Which framework do you use?

Comment: I am using zend framework. But is it possible when i connect to mysql  then i pass some value to mysql.And that will be save some where in that connected session of mysql or some global variable etc.